# Incorrect tooltip for inbox messages before manual page refresh

Tags: bug, status-norepro, top-bar, global-inbox, tooltips

When you have unread inbox messages the topbar inbox button contains an indicator with number and tooltip is saying *"You have unread inbox messages"*:

> [image: right]

Now you can click on the button to see unread messages in the popup window and close the popup. After that indicator with number has dissapered, but tooltip still contains the old text:

> [image: wrong]

You need to manually refresh the page to put the text in order with actual state:

> [image: right again]

Same behaviour can be observed in the opposite case, when the page is loaded completely before you got new notification:

> [image: incorrect]

Comment: That's strange, little bug is appearing, (can you please reply my comment, because i want to test... :D)

Comment: @U9-Forward test

Comment: Oh yeah, really is a bug.

Comment: Can you please post a comment to me again?

Comment: @U9-Forward no!

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't repro this, so it looks like it's been fixed?

For testing, you can trigger the indicator from your browser JavaScript console by running:

```js
// off
StackExchange.topbar.handleRealtimeMessage('{"Inbox":{"UnreadInboxCount":0}}');

// on
StackExchange.topbar.handleRealtimeMessage('{"Inbox":{"UnreadInboxCount":1}}');
```